# SZTV News: 外交部告诫美方：敌人是病毒不是中国: please correct my transcription

Tags: listening, transcription

To improve my listening, I tried listening to [外交部告诫美方：敌人是病毒不是中国](https://haokan.baidu.com/v?vid=3930263193047046216&pd=bjh&fr=bjhauthor&type=video) from SZTV News (Shenzhen), 21 April 2020.  Most of it has a transcription already, so I don't need that part.  This is what I hear:

> 应对日益严重国内疫情，美国总统特郎普频频妄图甩锅中国。他[**往常(?)**]在新冠疫情的问题向中国故意误导了国外社会，还频繁拿病毒源头做文章。对此外交部表示美方一些人应该尊重事实、尊重科学、应该认识到他们的敌人是病毒不是中国。
>
> 特朗普之外西方部分政客和媒体[**接(?)**]疫情[**大四选人**(?)]向中国索赔的论调。对此都[**ming2(?)**]外国政要和学者都看不下去了。捷克总统泽曼和新加坡国立大学李光耀公共政策学院[**chuang4(?)**]是院长马凯说[**等(?)**]人都做出了反驳。

Would it be possible to correct this transcription please?  (This time it's only 36 seconds worth of news.)

---

It says something like: Trump repeats attempt to shift the coronavirus blame to China, misleads the international community, and makes a fuss.  In response, China says respect facts and science, and be aware that the enemy is coronavirus, not China.  Western politicians and media join university students in arguing that China should pay compensation.  Experts think that is not going to happen.  The Czech president and Singaporean professor Ma Kai have put out refutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I come!

> 应对日益严重国内疫情，美国总统特<del>郎</del>**朗**普频频妄图甩锅中国。他**妄称**在新冠疫情的问题<del>向</del>**上**，中国故意误导了国外社会，还频繁拿病毒源头做文章。对此外交部表示美方一些人应该尊重事实、尊重科学、应该认识到他们的敌人是病毒不是中国。
>
> 特朗普之外西方部分政客和媒体**借**疫情**大肆渲染**向中国索赔的论调。对此<del>都[ming2(?)]</del>**多名**外国政要和学者都看不下去了。捷克总统泽曼和新加坡国立大学李光耀公共政策学院<del>[chuang4(?)]是</del>**创始**院长马凯说等人都做出了反驳。